# call a vector of names for grid.arrange

Tags: r, list, gridextra, r-grid

lets say I have a list called `ALL` with 40 elements, each of which is a `ggplot`.

if i want to plot one of these i can do

```
ALL[[1]]
```

or

```
print(ALL)
```

if i want to plot them all together i can do

```
grid.arrange(ALL[[1]] ,ALL[[2]], ALL[[3]], ....  )
```

or

```
grid.arrange(ALL[[names(ALL)[1]]] ,ALL[[names(ALL)[2]]], ALL[[names(ALL)[3]]], ....  )
```

This is really tiring with many list elements. But i cannot figure out how to just call `grid.arrange` to plot all plots. I don't want to `apply` over the list because i want multiple plots on the same page.

Calling 40 plots to `grid.arrange` may seem a lot but they are small plots and even for 1:10 plots on a page this is a lot of typing!!!!

Comment: Try `do.call(grid.arrange, ALL)`.

Comment: Cheers Josh, would you like to make an answer so i can accept this may be useful for other SOers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you've got a list (here your `ALL`) whose elements are the arguments you'd like passed in to a function (here `grid.arrange`), you can use [**`do.call`**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html).

This should do the trick:

```
## Equivalent to grid.arrange(ALL[[1]], ALL[[2]], ..., ALL[[n]])
do.call(grid.arrange, ALL)
```